# Identifiability of a bivariate normal distribution with identified minimum

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, extreme-value, bivariate

I am suffering from to understand a proof of a paper.
(Nádas, Arthur. "The distribution of the identified minimum of a normal pair determines' the distribution of the pair." Technometrics 13.1 (1971): 201-202.)

Consider a normally distributed random vector $[X_0,X_1]$ (mean: $\mu_0,\mu_1$, variance: $\sigma^2_0,\sigma^2_1$, correlation: $\rho$).

We cannot observe the random vector, but we can only observe $Z=\min\{X_0,X_1\}$ and $I=\mathbf{1}[X_0>X_1]$.

That is, we know the value of the minimum, $Z$, and what was the minimum, $I$.

---

The purpose of the paper is to show that using the information in $[Z,I]$, we can know the joint distribution of $[X_0,X_1]$.

The main proposition states
**"The distribution $H$ of the observable pair $[Z,I]$ uniquely determines the distribution of the unobservable pair $[X_0,X_1]$."**

I think, this proposition says that we can identify the distribution (the normal distribution parameters $[\mu_0,\mu_1,\sigma_0,\sigma_1,\rho]$) examining the observable data $[Z,I]$.

---

**The proof is as follows:**

We can show that the conditional density of $Z$ given $I=i$, for all $z$ and $i=0,1$, is given by
\begin{align*}\tag{1}
f_i(z)=\begin{cases}
p_i^{-1}n(z|\mu_i,\sigma^2_i)[1-N((z-\mu^*_i)/\sigma^*_i|0,1)] \quad if \quad \rho\sigma_{1-i}\neq \sigma_i \\[2pt]
n(z|\mu_i,\sigma^2_i)\quad otherwise
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
where $f_i(z)=\Pr[Z=z|I=i]$, $p_i=\Pr[I=i]$, $n(\cdot|a,b^2)$ is the normal density with mean $a$ and variance $b^2$, $N(\cdot|a,b^2)$ is the CDF. ($\mu^*_i$ and $\sigma^*_i$ are proper parameters.)

**With the given condition $(1)$, the main part of the proof says that**

Let $[\mu'_0,\mu'_1]$ and $[\sigma'_0, \sigma'_1, \sigma'_{01}]$ be parameters defining any bivariate normal density for which $[Z,I]$ has the distribution $H$. From $(1)$, we see that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{z\rightarrow -\infty}p_if_i(z)/n(z|\mu_i,\sigma^2_i)=\lim_{z\rightarrow -\infty}p_if_i(z)/n(z|\mu'_i,\sigma'^2_i)=1
\end{align*}
so that $n(z|\mu_i,\sigma^2_i)/n(z|\mu'_i,\sigma'^2_i)$ tends to unity. It follows that $\mu_i=\mu'_i$ and $\sigma_i=\sigma'_i$ and then $\rho=\rho'$ based on the fact that
\begin{align*}
p_0=\Pr(X_0-X_1<0)=\int^A_{-\infty}n(x|0,1)dx
\end{align*}
where $A=(\mu_0-\mu_1)/(\sigma^2_0+\sigma^2_1-2\rho \sigma_0\sigma_1)^{1/2}$.

---

Here, I am pretty confused especially from the "limit is one" statement. The purpose of the proof should may be to show the 1:1 relationship between the distribution of $[Z,I]$ and $[X_0,X_1]$. But, I have no idea the logit of this proof.

Comment: If both densities are identical a.e., they are identical at $\pm\infty$.

Comment: @Xi'an So, what is the role of the limits in the proof..? Why are they needed?

Comment: Looking at this specific value of $z$, $z=-\infty$, for equalling the densities, rather than at another one, easily shows that all parameters are equal.